Excel: Can text be combined from several cells & inserted into a structured table formula inside the brackets?
Assuming: Cell A1 = "Hi" and A2 = "Bye"
Structured Table column 1 = "Hi - Bye"
Can I reference column 1 in the structured table named "TABLE" by concatenating Cells A1 & A2 along with a hyphen such as:
Table[[#Headers],[CONCATENATE(A1," - ",A2)]]

Or must it only be hard-coded such as: Table[[#Headers],[Hi - Bye]]

With INDIRECT:
=INDIRECT("Table[[#Headers],["&A1&"-"&A2&"]]")

